# S3 Read-Modify-Write Atomicity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following use case. I have a JSON file in a S3 bucket.

I have a program, of which multiple instances can run in parallel. The program has a routine that modifies that JSON file in the S3 file by

1. Downloading it
2. Manipulating it in memory (eg adding a new key)
3. Uploading it back to S3

The problem is that if two instances (A and B) run this routine at the same time and if A downloads the file before B modifies it (or vice versa), A could end up overriding the changes made by B (even if the changes made by B are unrelated at all to the changes made by A)

Is there a way to use S3 in a way that guarantees Read-Modify-Write atomicity? ie this entire combination of actions atomic so that even if you have multiple threads of it running in parallel, they wouldn't interfere?

I know that in general, you'd use some form of a distributed lock. But I'm trying to see if there's a way to do it just with S3.

Comment: Yes, S3 supports strong read after write consistency by default.
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/

Comment: This can not be done with S3 alone.  In all of the [APIs S3 offers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations_Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service.html), there is no concept of a lock or other synchronization primitive, meaning some external party needs to act as a gate keeper.